# Run Spring MVC webapp with different configuration during integration tests

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I'm using the `maven-jetty-plugin` to run my Spring MVC webapp during the `integration-test` phase of a Maven build, and run various tests on it. At this point, I'd like to be able to switch out some of the Spring configuration, so that I can point at a different bean implementation during the integration tests. This is so that I can change which database to run against, rather than use the production connection settings.

What sort of approach should I consider? Should I attempt to use resource filtering on the servlet-context.xml file? Should I have two different configuration files? How do I get this to play nicely with the Jetty plugin?

**EDIT**: I'm considering using Spring's Java-based `@Configuration` annotations in preference to the XML servlet-context file, and switching what sort of beans I construct based on environment variables or similar, but this feels wrong as well.

Comment: Is your spring version >= 3.1 ?

Comment: @JintianDeng Yes, I'm running with Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest using spring profile+maven filtering:

1. Define a property in pom.xml which can ben overwritten via command line: -Dspring.profile.active=development

   ```
        <properties>
               <spring.profile.active>test</spring.profile.active>
        </properties>
   ```
2. Add resource filtering in pom.xml. Make sure your web.xml is in directory src/main/resources.

   ```
    <resources>  
          <resource>  
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>  
            <filtering>true</filtering>  
          </resource>  
    </resources>
   ```
3. Active the specific spring profile in web.xml, ${spring.profile.active} will be replaced after filtering.

   ```
   <context-param>  
       <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>  
       <param-value>${spring.profile.active}</param-value>  
   </context-param>
   ```
4. Define beans in spring profile

   ```
   <beans profile="production">  
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource"/>  
   </beans>
   ```

Comment: Although I did not follow this exact set of changes, this answer did point me towards the excellent Maven Properties plugin, which allowed me to bind setting the `spring.profiles.active` property to the `pre-integration-test` phases -- which was enough to inject different @Profile-annotated beans.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I always create a profile that contains jetty-maven-plugin configurations and integration tests configurations.

But when I learned about spring-test-mvc, I switched to it because everything that you want to achieve in integration tests using jetty-maven-plugin can be achieve. Plus, you can mock the services needed (eg. authentication in different app).

So I suggest to switch to spring-test-mvc. IMHO, jetty-maven-plugin style is quite painful.

Comment: That looks useful for using mock HTTP requests and responses for unit tests, but I really want to be able to run my webapp in Jetty to perform end-to-end acceptance tests, using Selenium for example.

Comment: You can use the suggestion of @Jintian DENG + properties-maven-plugin. Activate a spring profile by setting spring.profiles.active property during pre-integration-test